# ios crash on NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://locationofurlonlocalhost.mp4"];

...

NSMutableURLRequest *req;
req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url // <-- CRASH IS HERE!! thx to a breakpoint stepthrough
          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
          timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

a log of url will result in:

```
Printing description of url:
<NSURLRequest http://locationofurlonlocalhost.mp4>
```

the crash will log

```
-[NSURLRequest absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88003e0
```

The URL looks just fine so I'm not sure what's going on. Could this happen because the url is unreachable the simulator? I can connect to the url on the sim's safari as well as my desktop safari. What should I do?

** EDIT **

it's been determined that the url object is being released too early. In the `...` the url is passed to a different selector and then the rest of the code takes place there. How can I force retain the url? I have already tried:

```
__strong NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://locationofurlonlocalhost.mp4"];
```

Comment: is the URL to a file within your application package itself?  or is the URL to a file on a remote server somewhere?  are there any spaces in the URL?

Comment: @赢郭88888888 I think you're right. I'm using ARC so how can I make sure that my object doesn't release until I'm using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most definitely looks like your url has been released somehow. If you print the description of the `url` variable and wind up with an `NSURLRequest`, then you're looking at freed up memory.

Try using alloc / initWithString: as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: `__strong NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://10.10.1.3/html5/assets/trailer_test.mp4"];` still getting the same crash. I think you've put me on the right track though. FYI the url is passed in as a parameter to the selector where I am then trying to use it (but it's already been released).

Comment: As embarrassing as it is, in one of my loops I was changing the NSURL to a NSURLRequest. You can tell by the error. Oh wellz..